# View controller added in app delegate not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, presentviewcontroller

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let auth: UIViewController =
        storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Auth") as UIViewController

    window?.rootViewController?.present(auth, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return true
}
```

I get the error...

> Warning: Attempt to present 
>   on  whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

I presume the root controller has not been properly configured at this point in the app life cycle.

How do I do this? I want to avoid having the root controller having to check whether it needs to show the login screen.

Comment: You can conditionally check for login status and then set root view controller. If not logged in set root view controller as login else your home view controller

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to avoid having the root controller having to check whether it needs to show the login screen." ? You always want to show Logic screen and you login screen has Auth identifier?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko Not if they're already logged in when the app starts.

Comment: @Deepak But then how would I have the login controller reveal the main screen?

Comment: @IanWarburton i assume after successful login you send user to the main screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if Settings.appSettings.authToken != nil {
        self.showMainController()
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .authorizationOperationDidSuccess,
        object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        self.showMainController()
    }

    return true
}

private func showMainController() {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let controller: UIViewController =
        storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as UIViewController
    if self.window == nil {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.window?.rootViewController = controller
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

private func showAuthorizationController() {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let controller: UIViewController =
        storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Auth") as UIViewController
    if self.window == nil {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.window?.rootViewController = controller
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

On successful login make

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .authorizationOperationDidSuccess,
                    object: nil)
```

Comment: But there won't be a transition?

Comment: You can set Auth viewController as initial in storyboard, or you can add else statement, for example:  if Settings.appSettings.authToken != nil { self.showMainController() } else {
 self. showAuthorizationController() }

Answer (score 0):

Make change here,

```
let auth: AuthVC =  storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Auth") as AuthVC

// AuthVC is your_VC_name
```

Still facing issue, you can ask.